# How to print the name of tuple in Django?

Tags: python, list, django-models, django-templates

How can I print the Audio in the template?

```
class Product(models.Model):
 SERVICES = [
            ('Audio',  (('vinyl', 'Vinyl'),('cd', 'CD'))),
            ('Video',  (('vhs', 'VHS Tape'),('dvd', 'DVD'))),
            ('unknown', 'Unknown'),
        ]
 service                 = MultiSelectField(max_length=200,choices=SERVICES, blank=True, null=True,)
 title                   = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
 slug                    = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, blank=True, unique=True)
```

**Template file**

```
<option value="{% url 'booking'  %}" >{{products.service.0}}</option>
 <option value="{% url 'booking'  %}">{{products.service.1}}</option>
```

I am trying but I am getting values of tuple like "vinyl", "cd', Please suggest to me how can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you want to print? vinyl or Vinyl or cd or CD?

Comment: I need to print the "Audio" name which is the name of the first tuple.